# Will my heavy iPad app be rejected?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I am looking forward to submitting an iPad application which uses CoreAnimation a lot and so it's heavy.

In "App Store Review Guideline", it shows:

> 13.2 Apps that rapidly drain the device's battery or generate excessive heat will be rejected

While working my application on real iPad, it drains the battery to half in 4 hours, let the device to become a little bit warm. Will this be a reason enough to be rejected?

Comment: How much does it drain if you simply leave the screen on for 4 hours?  I guess about the same.

Comment: I've never tried to check how long my battery lasts, but referring http://www.macworld.com/article/1166128/new_ipads_battery_life_matches_apples_claims_but_ipad_2_lasts_longer.html it seems to last about 10-13 hrs.